# How to gracefully close a form if an exception occurs on that form in C#

Tags: c#, forms, exception

I am in a position where I have a large user app that has quite a few forms and I am looking for a way to close a single form if an exception has occurred due to some logic that has been caught on that form.

Right now I am following the principal of 'don't write try/catch everywhere to catch boneheaded mistakes' and it does make my code cleaner, but causes crashes the entire app when I have a NullPointerException.

The best solution would be a 'local error handler' that each form would have that would collect any exceptions at that level and kill the form there instead of it bubbling up and killing the entire app.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Exceptions don't happen on Forms. They happen on Threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you derive your forms from a common base class, so they can share the same error handler?  We have a base form that logs the exception, displays an error, and then closes the form (which is optional in debug mode).  Every user event (button_click for example) is wrapped in a try/catch that calls the base error handler.

Also, in case you didn't know, there are global exception handlers:

[Application.ThreadException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)

[AppDomain.UnhandledException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

[WindowsFormsApplicationBase.UnhandledException event (VB)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.unhandledexception.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

> but causes crashes the entire app when I have a NullPointerException.

Then you need to fix the `NullReferenceException(s)`, not come up with some convoluted mechanism for catching exceptions at the global level and backtracking to find the form which caused it.  You should simply (try to) design your code so that null references are impossible to occur, or if they do, it can be handled in a graceful manner.

If you have a scenario which causes a crash, fix it, don't ignore it.  How can you guarantee that closing the form will leave your program in a consistent state, now and in the future?  (HINT: You can't)

Comment: NullPointerException is just one instance. There are hundreds of different issues that can occur, some benign, some of them not so benign. The forms are set up to be independent of each other and are very loosely coupled. If an error occurs on one form, it will not affect the others. I am using this because as one programmer I cannot catch 100% of the bugs in an application, this is a failsafe that will let the error be logged and me to fix it with minimal impact to the end user.

Comment: @Austin: You can never (provably) catch 100% of the bugs in your app, but it doesn't mean that the approach you want to take is the best option. You can always catch AppDomain.UnhandledException, but still, your idea is just as bad as putting try/catch blocks everywhere, but instead the mechanism is "hidden" and unobvious. As a user I would not appreciate my form(s) closing for some unknown reason because you as a developer did not want to spend the time to fix the real problem.

Comment: Realize that this is only a fall-back to be fixed once I know of an issue. The bugs are going to exist today whether I wrap them or not, which means the best case scenario is a user's application crashes. If i wrap them in one place, let the user know what is going on, close the one troubled form, and send that bug information back to myself to fix, the speed of bug fixing is much quicker than having the user say 'my application crashed' and having the same exact information and an error. at least they can continue their work